# How to check if data exist in SQL table using EF code first in ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this model class:

```
public class MembershipSerial
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
    public string Serial { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Membership Serial")]
    public string SerialConfirmed { get; set; }
}
```

I am using EF code-first approach, I would like to check the value of the Serial vs SerialConfirmed and find any Serial which is equal to SerialConfirmed.

I tried below but i get a null exception and don't know how to solve this?

```
    public ActionResult Checkout(UserDetails Details)
    {
        if (Details.MembershipSerial.Serial.Any().ToString() == Details.MembershipSerial.SerialConfirmed)
        {
            return View("UserSerial");
        }

        return View();
    }

    public class UserDetails : IdentityUser
    {
        public virtual DeliveryDetails DeliveryDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual UserOrders UserOrders { get; set; }
        public virtual MembershipSerial MembershipSerial { get; set; }
    }
```

**Edit:**

```
public class MembershipSerial
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
    public string Serial { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Membership Serial")]
    public string SerialConfirmed { get; set; }
}

public class DeliveryDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string District { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
}
public class UserOrders
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<UserDetails>
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base ("EFDbContext")
    {
    }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MembershipSerial> MembershipSerial { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<DeliveryDetails> DeliveryDetails { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<UserOrders> UserOrders { get; set; }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want to check if any `Serial` in the database equals the `SerialConfirmed` that user is *Checking In*?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement should be like this:

```
 if (Details.MembershipSerial.Serial == Details.MembershipSerial.SerialConfirmed)
```

Serial and Serial Confirmed are strings so you can just compare them

Comment: didn't work i can't get where after MembershipSerial

Comment: It gives a null exception

Comment: check if Details and Details.MembershipSerial are not null

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to compare any `Serial` in the database with the `SerialConfirmed` that the user is *Checking Out* then you need a variable to hold a new instance of your connection string: assuming that `MemberShipSerial` is a table in your database...

```
using(var db = new ConnectionString())
{
    if(db.MembershipSerial.Any(x => x.Serial.ToUpper() == Details.MembershipSerial.SerialConfirmed.ToUpper())
    {
        /*do something*/
    }
 }
```

if you just want to compare `Serial` and `SerialConfirmed` based on what the user typed in then use

```
if(Details.MembershipSerial.Serial.ToUpper() == Details.MembershipSerial.SerialConfirmed.ToUpper())
```

if the second option returns a null exception then you have to debug on the `CheckingIn` Action and see if what those properties are holding the values you are expecting

Comment: and what is this `.ToUpper`

Comment: and by the way can't get the `.Any()` after the MembershipSerial

Comment: `.ToUpper` is something that I think is efficient and effective to check strings against other strings.. if you want to compare John vs. john... the two words are the same obviously but the database will accept john bc the J isn't capitalized.. so `.ToUpper` will do JOHN vs JOHN, which will show that they are the exact same

Comment: can you post your `UserDetails` class?

Comment: okay, yeah if you want to check the `SerialConfirmed` against any `Serial` in your database then you need a variable to hold a new instance of your Connection String, or if the `ActionResult CheckOut` is in a controller.. the variable holding a new instance of your connection string can be found new the top.